# How do I display quiz questions with their options and to save selected option in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I am pretty new to Angular so I find this portion confusing. I am trying to display a list of questions obtained from the database (ASP.NET Core 2.0 as web API) and to show their options, for each question. The questions and options are in a one-to-many relationship (database design).

However, I do not know how to display the questions and their respective options in one single page and to obtain the question id and their selected options. I am trying to use reactive forms for this method. My code is below.

checklistform.component.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="CheckListForm">
         <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block"> Name:
   <input class="form-control" formControlName = "name">
  </label>
     </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="center-block"> Employement Type:
  <input class="form-control" formControlName = "EmploymentType">
 </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block"> HRMS:
    <input class="form-control" formControlName = "HRMS">
 </label>
   </div>


  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="center-block"> CompanyName:
   <input class="form-control" formControlName = "CompanyName">
  </label>
      </div>


   <div formArrayName="questions" class="well well-lg">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions.controls; let i=index" 
     [formGroupName]="i" >
            <div class="form-group">

                    //template for questions and options must be listed 
                       here.
```

This is my .ts file.
checklistform.component.ts

```
       import { ChecklistService } from './../service/checklist.service';
       import { Component, OnInit,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormGroup,
                 FormBuilder,
                  FormArray,
                 FormControl,
                  Validators, } from '@angular/forms';


              @Component({
                  selector: 'app-check-list-form',
                   templateUrl: './check-list-form.component.html',
                   styleUrls: ['./check-list-form.component.css']
                                                                  })
           export class CheckListFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{


                    CheckListForm: FormGroup;


              Questions: any = [];

              constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
                      private checklistservice: ChecklistService) { 
                   this.CreateForm();

                                    }

              ngOnInit() { 

     this.checklistservice.getQuestions(1).subscribe(res => this.Questions = 
             res); }

              ngOnChanges() {

                            }

            CreateForm() {

             this.CheckListForm = this.fb.group({

                name: ['', Validators.required],
              EmploymentType: ['', Validators.required],
              HRMS: ['', Validators.required],
             CompanyName:'',

            questions: this.fb.array([

             this.fb.group({

           ques: ['', Validators.required],
             choices: ['', Validators.required]
          })
           ]) 

          })
           }

             get questions(): FormArray {
             return this.CheckListForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
               }
              }
```

Please help. I have tried searching through the internet but I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: i have already done so. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers provided are correct.

To solve this problem, you need to use the following:

1. FormGroup
2. Formarray.

You will need to iterate the model through the FormArray and then display the options accordingly for each question.

You will need to use reactive forms for this approach i have suggested.

All your questions and their options will be shown in a single page.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is like below then it would be better to handle

```
 Questions: any[] = [
       {
          'Question': 'question-1',
          'Options': [
            {
              "id": 1
              "option": "A"
            },
            {
               "id": 2
              "option": "B"
            },
          ]
        },
         {
          'Question': 'question-2',
          'Options': [
            {
               "id": 1
              "option": "A"
            },
            {
                "id": 2
              "option": "B"
            },
          ]
        }
    ]
```

HTML

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
    <!-- we will place our fields here -->

    <!-- name -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
        <!--display error message if name is not valid-->
        <small *ngIf="!myForm.controls.name.valid" class="text-danger">
            Name is required (minimum 5 characters).
        </small>
    </div>

    <!-- list of Question -->
    <div formArrayName="questions">
        <div *ngFor="let question of Questions; let i=index">


            <!-- Angular assigns array index as group name by default 0, 1, 2, ... -->
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <!--street-->
                <div *ngFor="let opt of question.Options; let j=index">
                    <label>Option : </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="Option1" value="1">
                    <!--display error message if street is not valid-->

                </div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try this

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply. However, i am obtaining question values and options from the database instead. Furthermore, i will need to submit my responses to and store them in the database, where i capture the selected options for each question.

Comment: Thanks for the modifications. However, when i try to run the code, i get this error on my console:   uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "form". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

Comment: Hi there, you you have updates on the codes? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListBox control from PrimeNG UI components to display questions. Below is the link of PrimeNG ListBox control

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox

You can refer below blog to understand more about PrimeNG package installation and how to use in Angular application.

http://hive.rinoy.in/how-to-add-primeng-ui-components-in-asp-net-core-2-and-angular-web-application/

Comment: this does not totally answer the question.